# Is the set of extended real-valued measurable functions a vector space?

Tags: measure-theory

> Definition: Let $(\Omega, \Sigma)$ and $(\Omega', \Sigma')$ be
> measurable spaces. A map $f: \Omega \to \Omega'$ is
> $\Sigma$-$\Sigma'$-measurable if $f^{-1}(A') \in \Sigma$ for all $A'
> \in \Sigma'$.

The lecture notes state that for functions $f: \Omega \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ we always choose the Borel $\sigma$-Algebra $\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}}) = \{B \cup A: B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), A \subset \{-\infty,\infty\} \}$ for $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

There is also a theorem that proves that the sum of two measurable functions $f,g: \Omega \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is measurable and that $cf$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is measurable. Note that the lecture notes work with the following definitions:

$0 \cdot (\pm \infty) := (\pm \infty) \cdot 0 := 0$ and $\infty - \infty := -\infty + \infty := 0$

After this the lecture notes remark that the set of measurable functions from $\Omega$ to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ forms a vector space.

However, I think this is not true since $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is not a field, in particular the distributive law does not hold. We can also give a concrete counterexample: Let $f(x)=\infty$ for all $x \in \Omega$, then $f$ is measurable since it's constant (preimages of Borel sets are either empty or $\Omega$). But

$(2-1) \cdot f(x) = 1 \cdot \infty = \infty \neq 0 = \infty - \infty = 2 \cdot \infty - 1 \cdot \infty = 2 \cdot f(x) - 1 \cdot f(x)$,

so the vector space axiom $(a+b)v = av + bv$ for vectors $v$ and scalars $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ does not hold.

Am I correct or am missing anything?

Comment: $f-g$ may not be defined for measurable functions $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Well, with the definitions I gave it is always defined, isn't it? If $f(x)-g(x)=\infty - \infty$, then we simply define the value of $f-g$ at $x$ to be $0$.

Comment: $\infty -\infty =0$ is a strange convention. Normally, the space to considered should be $\{f:\Omega \to \bar {\mathbb R}\mid f\text{measurable and }f^-<\infty \}$ where $f^-(x)=-\min \{f(x),0\}$.

Comment: @Surb Well, it is really only used to define sums of functions more easily. The integral is first defined for nonnegative functions and then the integral of an arbitrary function is defined as the difference of the integrals of the positive and negative parts of that function as long as at least one is not infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. This is not a vector space.

In practice, this does not matter much, since usually one

1. Identifies functions that are equal almost everywhere, and
2. Is only interested in functions that are finite almost everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I guess the author intended to say that the set of functions from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$ forms a vector space, which should be true since those functions satisfy the subspace criteria and the real-valued functions on any set form a vector space.

Comment: @DerivativesGuy: That is definitely true. But some authors simply write that the extended valued functions are a vector space as well, without thinking much about it. Back in my Analysis class I won some sweets as a reward for pointing out the thing you discovered. :D

Comment: Haha, yeah it easily happens because we usually show that something is a vector space using the subspace criterion. But in this case this is not sufficient.